# Prevent column moving/rearranging

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using [UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/). I have a plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hY2LZJfMWa6Sm4yPG8P9?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ui.grid.moveColumns']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function ($scope, $http, $log) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {};

  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name:'id', width:50, pinnedLeft:true  },
    { name:'name', width:100, pinnedLeft:true },
    { name:'age', width:100, pinnedLeft:true  },
    { name:'company', width:100},
    { name:'address.street', width:150  },
    { name:'address.city', width:150 },
    { name:'address.state', width:50 },
    { name:'address.zip', width:50 },
    { name:'email', width:100 },
    { name:'phone', width:200 },
    { name:'about', width:300 },
    { name:'friends[0].name', displayName:'1st friend', width:150 },
    { name:'friends[1].name', displayName:'2nd friend', width:150 },
    { name:'friends[2].name', displayName:'3rd friend', width:150 },
  ];
  $scope.gridOptions.jqueryUIDraggable= false;

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

, where I want to achieve the following:

1. the first 3 columns to be pinned to the left
2. I want to be able to move/rearrange the other non-pinned columns by drag-dropping them

I was able to achieve both.

However, I was not able to STOP/prevent drag-drop of the columns that are pinned. 
How can I prevent certain columns from being drag-dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app.js, try adding enableColumnMoving:false to the columnDefs like so:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ui.grid.moveColumns']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function ($scope, $http, $log) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {};

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
{ name:'id', width:50, pinnedLeft:true, enableColumnMoving:false },
{ name:'name', width:100, pinnedLeft:true, enableColumnMoving:false },
{ name:'age', width:100, pinnedLeft:true, enableColumnMoving:false  },
{ name:'company', width:100},
{ name:'address.street', width:150  },
{ name:'address.city', width:150 },
{ name:'address.state', width:50 },
{ name:'address.zip', width:50 },
{ name:'email', width:100 },
{ name:'phone', width:200 },
{ name:'about', width:300 },
{ name:'friends[0].name', displayName:'1st friend', width:150 },
{ name:'friends[1].name', displayName:'2nd friend', width:150 },
{ name:'friends[2].name', displayName:'3rd friend', width:150 },
];    

$http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
.success(function(data) {
  $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
});
}]);
```

Comment: Cool! This is exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Better solution seven years later - suppressMovable:true in the column def.

For all columns:

public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
sortable: false,
filter: false,
resizable:true,
suppressMovable:true
};